# How do I mock a data layer in WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, nunit, moq

I have a WCF service which is hosted using wshttpbinding under windows service.

```
public interface ICalculator
{
  public IDataLayer DataLayer {get;set;}

public List<string> GetResult()
{
  return DataLayer.Calculate();
}
```

I have hosted the service and added service reference in my test class library.  I want to mock out data layer so I can verify whether the Calculate method was called or not.  How do I mock the DataLayer reference?

What is the testing strategy for WCF? Should I host the service first and carry out the tests or should I test the service DLL first and then host it?

I am using MOQ and NUnit.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To get a canned response:

```
var mock = new Mock<IDataLayer>();
mock.Setup(d => d.Calculate()).Returns("what ever value you want to return");
```

To make sure it was called:

```
mock.Verify(d=> d.Calculate());
```

You will need to unit test the WCF class by itself first to verify behavior.  Actually hosting the service and using a proxy client is an integration test.

So create a NUnit TestFixture for the service (which I guess is Calculator).  Treat it in NUnit as a normal class, and carry out all your tests, mock out the DataLayer to get canned results back and assert whether it was called or not when you expect it to be called.

Comment: Hi, are you suggesting that I should add the class reference of the service layer DLL directly and carry out the tests.  Once they pass, I should just host it?  Or should I host it and then carry out the tests?

Comment: You carry out the unit tests on the Service class as you would any normal user-defined class.  Then when all of your expectations of that class are done host it and either do integration tests with a proxy client or create a new suite of tests for the user of the service (whichever that class would be) and you can mock out the behavior of the wcf service or actually host it inside the unit tests and verify your expectations on the client.